# How to truncate in C

Tags: c, string

Using Xcode.

How do I remove the first x number of characters in a string, where x is a finite value?

For example, if I have a string:

```
s = 123.456.789
```

how do I delete the first 4 characters to make:

```
s = 456.789
```

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 char *s = "123.456.789"
 s += 4;
 printf("%s\n", s); // will print 456.789
```

Comment: Applied without thought this approach sets a trap for the unwary when they start using dynamically allocated memory; there is nothing wrong with it as shown here, but watch out for losing your `free`able handle if the string resides in `malloc`ed memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *tmp=strdup(oldstr);
strcpy(oldstr, &tmp[4]);  // copy from character # 5 back into old string
free(tmp);
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
void remove_first_x(char *s, int x) {
    char *p = s+x;
    memmove(s, p, strlen(p)+1);
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = "123.456.789";  // String defined this way should not be modified.
                                 // C++ compiler warns you if you define a string
                                 // like this! Better define it as "const char *".

    char str2[] = "123.456.789"; // String defined this way can be modified

    remove_first_x(str1, 4);     // Not safe!
    remove_first_x(str2, 4);     // Safe!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In most implementations this will segfault if applied to a automatic string (i.e. one that appears inside `"`s in the code.

Comment: @dmckee, I agree with you. But, when you declare a string like that, it should be declared as "const char *". This function takes a "char *" and you can safely send strings that are modifiable. I will update my example to reflect that.